# NPM Global installation

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node and added few packages globally. I could packages are added in two locations. one is

```
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules 
     and other location is C:\Users\ananthik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Why packages are installed in both locations?

which location is used for saving dependency, when we use `-g`.

In Environmental user variable `C:\Users\ananthik\AppData\Roaming\npm` this path is added.

Comment: Run `npm list -g` and check where they are installed